# Query between 2 timestamps that is in a custom field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using `wordpress 5.3.2` and `advanced custom fields pro Version 5.8.7`.

My custom field is called `timestamp`. See below my ACF configuration:

[image]

I tried to query the db like the following:

```
            $today = new DateTime();
            $timestToday = $today->getTimestamp();

            $timestPlus1 = strtotime('+1 days', $timestToday);

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'Calendar-Events',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_status' => array('publish', 'draft'),
                'meta_key' => 'timestamp',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'key' => 'timestamp',
                    'value' => array($timestToday, $timestPlus1),
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                    'type' => 'DATE'
                ),
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            );

            $posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

The SQL that this query looks like the following:

```
SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'timestamp' 
  AND 
  ( mt1.meta_key = 'timestamp' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) BETWEEN '1577568776' AND '1577655176' )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'calendar-events' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC
```

However, I get as result all posts back and also posts that have the `timestamp` field `""` and NOT only the posts that are between the timestamp.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it. Instead of `'type' => 'DATE'` must be used `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` for `timestamps`.